# PowerShell script to check the names of all directories and create subfolders in each one

Tags: regex, powershell, rename

I have a Main folder which contains many folders with the name format: capital letter and four numbers (A4431). The script in Powershell I am trying to write needs to go through all the folders in my Main folder and check, if they have the correct name format and change it if it is not the correct one. After that it needs to create a subfolder structure in each folder in my main folder.The subfolder structure consists of 4 folders, one of which has its own subfolders.The names of the subfolder structure is always the same. The end result should look like this:

```
Main Folder
 **-A4431**
  -Customers
  -Supplier
  -Orders
    -Sub Folder1
    -Sub Folder2
  -Items
 **-C1131**
  -Customers
  -Supplier
  -Orders
    -Sub Folder1
    -Sub Folder2
  -Items
...
```

I am a begginer in Powershell, so the solution I have came up with is a total mess but I am posting it anyway.

```
$root = "C:\Work files\Test\Main folder"

#Folder name example (A3234)
$pattern = "^([a-zA-Z]){1}\d{4}"

#Subfolder structure needed to be created in each folder
$folders_names = "Customers","Supplier","Orders","Items"

#Get all folders in $root
$dirs = Get-ChildItem $root | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"}

#loop through all folders in root and check if they have the right name format and change it if necessary
ForEach ($dir in $dirs)
{
    if(!$dir -match $pattern){
        $newName = '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '([a-zA-Z]){1}\d{4}') 
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -Force 
    }
    #create subfolders in each folder in $root
    ForEach ($name in $folder_names){
        New-item -path "$root\$dir" -Name $name -Type 'directory'
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please specify your problem with the code. Knowing not much about Powershell myself, but your pattern should be `([A-Z])\d{4}` (no need of {1} and only A-Z, because you need a capital letter / I don't know which groups you need). Maybe https://regex101.com can help.

Comment: Hi @AndyA. I have added the non capital letters because I also consider it correct. The main problem is how to first check the folder names against the pattern and then change their name, so it will be correct. The second big issue is how to create the subfolder structure in each folder. So far I have not figured out how to create subfolders with their own subfolder. The code I have posted seems to not work at all.

Comment: ```$_``` only works inside a pipeline (e.g. ```$dirs | foreach-object { $_ ... etc ... }```). You probably mean ```$dir``` in your ```foreach( $dir in $dirs )```.

Comment: The renaming condition of the parent folder if pattern does not match is very unclear. You should provide more details on that.

Comment: Please elaborate on _" if they have the correct name format and change it if it is not the correct one"_. What if a folder is called 'imphetuss_stuff'.. rename that into ???? What would be the strategy there?

Comment: @mclayton The idea is that all folders in Main folder need to be one capital letter and four or more numbers after example: A2243, F3132... If a folder has a name different from this format it needs to be renamed to match that pattern of capital letter from A-Z and four numbers. Another questions is how to avoid name duplication... I hope this explanation clears things up

Comment: So basically, you want to rename folders with a different name format into some random name, as long as it starts with a capital letter, followed by 4 random numbers? Really? Also, change `if(!$dir -match $pattern)` into `if($dir -cnotmatch $pattern)`. The `c` makes the regex case-sensitive. Same goes for `-replace` vs. `-creplace`

Answer (score 1):

This should help get you started. It does not address the naming of the first level directories or the addition of the 3rd level directories but you should see the logic on how to accomplish this. Hint: $NewDir will contain the path of the created directory!

```
$Root = "C:\Work files\Test\Main folder"

[Array]$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Root -Directory -Depth 0

$NewFolds = @("Customers","Supplier","Orders","Items")

ForEach ($Dir in $Dirs) {

  $NIArgs = @{Path     = "$Root\$Dir"
              ItemType = "Directory"}

  For ($Cntr = 0; $Cntr -lt $NewFolds.Count; $Cntr++) {
    $NewDir = New-Item @NIArgs -Name $($NewFolds[$($Cntr)])
  } #End For ($Cntr...

} #End ForEach ($Dir..
```